# Read content from csv having delimiter in python using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read content from csv file. Below is the format of the file:

```
SOURCE_TYPE|SOURCE_QUERY|TARGET_QUERY
HIVE|SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USR_ID
       ORDER BY snap_logmarker DESC ) AS row_num  
       FROM   ( SELECT USR_ID,snap_logmarker
         FROM  ARCHIVE_db.a_cust_auth  
         WHERE (CONCAT(snapshot_year_month, snapshot_day) = '20171231')   
         UNION ALL   
         SELECT USR_ID,snap_logmarker FROM ( SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USR_ID ORDER BY snap_logmarker desc,snap_intentseq desc ) AS row_num 
         FROM staging_db.a_cust_auth   
         WHERE snapshot_year_month ='201801') C
                                WHERE C.row_num = 1
                   ) B
) A 
 WHERE A.row_num = 1
|
select * from db.cust_auth where concat(snapshot_year_month,snapshot_day)='20180131'
```

I want to separate all values in a list of string and delimiter used is "|" i.e

SOURCE_TYPE = HiVE

SOURCE_QUERY = complete sub query till | separator

TARGET_QUERY = last select query

Using pandas.read_csv, this structure of file cannot be parsed.

How can I separate values and store in list?

Comment: how is this a csv file, does not look comma delimited to me

Comment: @aws_apprentice - yes it is not a standard format of csv, but this is the only format i am receiving the file. This cannot be modified. I just want separate values for SOURCE_TYPE,SOURCE_QUERY and TARGET_QUERY in a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question, you can load the file but not parse it ?
You can store your file content in a variable then split it with the `split` method as you have a determined separator.

```
list_str = your_file_content.split("|")
```

It will return you a list with all your differents string in your file.

There are some example of this function :
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split

Comment: using split...the output will be SOURCE_TYPE|SOURCE_QUERY|TARGET_QUERY\nHIVE|... But I want it HIVE in separate field and from select till | separator in one field. There is a newline character after each line.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late answer... But maybe if someone have a similar issue, I'm not sure if I understood what you were expecting but, you can read the whole file, then split with '|' (It will let the \n, you can remplace it if it's an issue). Once it's done, you can start iterate on the array from the 3rd index, with a modulo 3 you'll be able to sperate each field

Answer (score 0):

A CSV files consists of records containing fields. The field separator is commonly the comma (`,`) but can be any character, and the record separator in normally the end of line (`'\r\n'`). Embedding of separator (include record separator) in a field normally requires the field to be enclosed in quotation marks.

Your file seems to contain one single record, with end of lines embedded in fields with no enclosing quotes: it is not a CSV file and should not be processes but a tool expecting a csv file.

Just read it and split it on `|`.